# How to use line item as an condition for Netsuite workflow

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a possible way to use a line-item custom field from a Transaction > Purchase Order type as a condition to trigger a Netsuite workflow?

For example: if I have a Purchase Order, and after a line item/items is updated to "Yes" of a custom field "Exported", I want to send an email confirmation to a specific person. However, the line-item custom field does not seem to be found when I add the condition.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a workflow, you can always go for a script (UserEvent) to avoid unwanted complexity.

You can use `email.send()` API from `N/email` module.

In the script, you can write the logic to find updated checkboxes by using `context.oldRecord` and `context.newRecord`.

Let me know if you need any additional information in comments below.